# Robot doesn't fall straight

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello.

I'm trying to simulate the behavior of my humanoid robot.
However, though all inertia are set correctly, my robot doesn't fall down straight and it can't stand still.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sUTHjCHQJ0

I have no idea what is going on.

How to fix this strange behavior and to make my robot fallen down straight?

I'm using gazebo 7.9.0 and ROS lunar.

my urdf is: https://github.com/Y-modify/yamax/blob/develop/src/yamax_description/robots/yamax.urdf

.launch file: https://github.com/Y-modify/yamax/blob/develop/src/yamax_gazebo/launch/world.launch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18133/robot-doesn%27t-fall-straight/) by [coord.e](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4114/coord.e/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like there might be some parameters not well set. I recommend you visually introspect your model to detect what's wrong:

1. Right-click it and choose View -> Center of Mass - the way it wobbles in the end suggests the center of mass may be hanging under the ground
2. View -> Inertia - the pink inertia boxes should be close to the size of each link
3. View -> Collisions - the orange collisions should also be close to the link sizes
4. On the top menu, choose View -> Contacts - the blue dots will show you when things are in contact

Hope that helps spot the errors!

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [coord.e](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4114/coord.e/) on 2018-01-06**:
Thank you!